# Where to start with: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n} - \sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2}) ((n^3 +3)^{12} - (n^4+4n)^9)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals

I have limit:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n} - \sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2}) ((n^3 +3)^{12} - (n^4+4n)^9)$

I have to find that it is equal to -6 but I do not know how.

What I did was to get rid of cube roots by multiply them with

$\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n})(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2})+  (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2})^2)}{(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n})(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2})+  (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2})^2)}$

which gives me:

$\dfrac{((n^{48}+n) - (n^{48}+n^2))((n^3 +3)^{12} - (n^4+4n)^9 )}{(\sqrt[3]{1n^{48}+n})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{1n^{48}+n})(\sqrt[3]{1n^{48}+n^2})+  (\sqrt[3]{1n^{48}+n^2})^2)}$

but I can not move from here other than just do

$\dfrac{(n - n^2)((n^3 +3)^{12} - (n^4+4n)^9) }{(\sqrt[3]{1n^{48}+n})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{1n^{48}+n})(\sqrt[3]{1n^{48}+n^2})+  (\sqrt[3]{1n^{48}+n^2})^2)}$

I am trying to find some known limits there or something I can grasp on, but can not find anything.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But that's what I did when multiplying with $\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n})(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2})+  (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2})^2}{(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n})(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2})+  (\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^2})^2})$ or not?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I misread.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No worries, I have been wondering if it is at least a good start? Because the formula I get after the multiplying is looking like it is getting me nowhere.

Comment: You still need to (at least) observe that the binomial formula expansions of both $(n^3+3)^{12}$ and $(n^4+4n)^9$ begin with $n^{36}+36n^{33}+\cdots$, so those terms cancel. The next terms on the other hand...

Comment: But, yes, that's a good start.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake both the numerator and the denominator will have a dominating term of constant times $n^{32}$. Just work out those next terms in those binomial formua expansions. I'm sure you can do it. Gotta commute next.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you, will work on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the 2nd term

$$((n^3+3)^{12}-(n^4+4n)^{9})\\
=((n^{36}+36n^{33}+594n^{30}+\cdots)-(n^{36}+36n^{33}+576n^{30}+\cdots))\\
=18n^{30}+\cdots$$

where the dots represent lower order terms. Expanding the 1st term

$$(\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n}-\sqrt[3]{n^{48}+n^{2}})\\
=n^{16}(\sqrt[3]{1+n^{-47}}-\sqrt[3]{1+n^{-46}})\\
=n^{16}((1+\frac{1}{3}n^{-47}+\cdots)-(1+\frac{1}{3}n^{-46}+\cdots))\\
=n^{16}(-\frac{1}{3}n^{-46}+\frac{1}{3}n^{-47}+\cdots)$$

The product of the two terms is:

$$(-6+6n^{-1}+\cdots)$$

which equals $-6$ in the limit.

Hope that helps